# Sony Bluetoothc headset WH-1000XM3 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, headphones

I have followed the threads here on SO, and have Bluez 5.52 installed too.
This is a desktop machine, so I am presuming there is no Bluetooth card, so I got myself a Bluetooth dongle too.
Now, whenever I start Bluez, it shows my device, and says "Congrats, your device is connected". However, my headphones do not cheer me up with the customary "Bluetooth connected", and of course I cannot hear the sound from the computer. Prior to installing Bluez, I think I had some other "system" Bluetooth, which would pair to my headphones too, but would fail to recognize them as such, having "Unknown" (or something) instead of "headphones". So, where should I look? I cannot do anything to the machine at this point (e.g. installing 20.04), but what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I installed blueman and it helped me with the recognition of my headset. I first deleted the previous profiles of attempted connections with the headphone saved in my PC (this was a required step).
Later I started a clean connection, it got recognized, then I selected Audio Sink profile instead of headset or handsfree. After this you must see the bars on the right side changing colors which means there is data being transferred.
Finally,in Blueman, right click on your device and change the "Audio profile" to A2DP sink.
Regards,
America